# Python Pyomo: Variables domain error in Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I want to solve an integer programming problem in which the decision variables are restricted in a specific set.

For example, decision variables xi must be chosen in [2,5,7,10].

For testing, I wrote the python code using Pyomo as follows:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = AbstractModel()
model.X = Set(initialize=[2, 5, 7, 10])
model.x = Var(within=model.X)
model.obj = Objective(expr=model.x+1)
m = model.create_instance()
opt = SolverFactory("glpk")
results = opt.solve(m)
```

When these codes are executed, I got an error message: 
"TypeError: Invalid domain type for variable with name 'x'. Variable is not continuous, integer, or binary"

Here are my questions:

- What is the reason of this error?
- How to deal with it?
- Is there any other optimization tools that can handle this type of problems?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Use Var(within=Integers, bounds=(1,3))

Comment: I didn't describe the problem clearly. Have fixed it. I have read the answers that you replied to other questions. It seems that you are an author of Pyomo? It's very thankful for you helping.How can I deal with this problem? @GabeHackebeil

Answer (score 3):

- *What is the reason of this error?*

  As the error indicates, mixed-integer linear solvers like GLPK can only handle continuous, binary, and general integer variables. When you specify

  ```
  model.X = Set(initialize=[2, 5, 7, 10])
  model.x = Var(within=model.X)
  ```

  You are trying to create a discrete categorical variable, which while Pyomo can represent internally, it has no way to pass to that particular solver.
- *How to deal with it?*

  There is a standard reformulation using a set of binary variables:

  ```
  model.X = Set(initialize=[2, 5, 7, 10])
  model.select_x = Var(model.X, domain=Binary)
  model.x = Var()
  def pick_one(m):
      return 1 == sum(m.selext_x[i] for i in m.X)
  model.pick_one = Constraint(rule=pick_one)
  def set_x(m):
      return m.x == sum(i*m.select_x[i] for i in m.X)
  model.set_x = Constraint(rule=set_x)
  ```
- *Is there any other optimization tools that can handle this type of problems?*

  While there are some solvers that can handle discrete categorical variables, you are probably better off using the above reformulation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Inspired by your answer to question 2, I reformulated the original problem by adding a SOS1 constraint to variable x and solve it with the Gurobi optimization tool.